# VS2012 debugger doesn't stop in specific class

Tags: c#, wpf

The problem I have is that my debugger doesn't enter my class Station when I create it in the mainwindow but he executes the class. I placed a breakpoint on `InitializeComponent();` I hit `F11` then the debugger highlights the `Station statie = new Station();` `F11` it highlights the next bracket. At this point I hover my mouse over statie and see the code has been executed it is not null.But when I edit my class with more code I wish to debug the class my debugger doens't go in the class even if I place a breakpoint in my class station.

I searched some debugger options to see if there are right but nothing really helps.(Tools -> options -> debugging -> general)

```
namespace NMBSLiveBoard
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Station statie = new Station();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the constructor for your Station class

Comment: Add a public constructor with no parameters to `Station` class. Ex: `public Station() { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to make an instace of my class in my xaml. this fixed my problem when i used a constructor in my class i had an infinte loop

Answer (score 1):

That is normal. The Station constructor is a default one meaning there is nothing to go into.

If you need to see debugging info of a method or some property you should assign it or call it (for a method).

All information about the object you just created should be available if you place your mouse over the newly created Station variable.

Comment: thx i had to add code to constructor now i did everything in the getter of an property. :(